# JPA - How to Save 3 tables which has onetoMany Relationship with each table

Tags: jpa

I Have a table in Following Relationship:
Table A have OneToMany Relationship with Table B
Table B have OneToMany Relationship with Table C.
I am using @JoinComun Anotation. The Values for Table B is getting saved properly but I am not able to save Table C values

Comment: Can you go into more detail what "not able to save" means.

Comment: you must not have marked cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST entity B

Comment: Can you post your entities and your code for persisting?